# Updating a prop in nested layout from a page in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to update the page title found in a nested layout.

**app/docs/layout.tsx**:

```
export const DocsLayout = ({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}) => {
   return (
      <>
         <header>
             <h2>Documentation - {/* platform goes here */}</h2>
         </header>

         <div>{children}</div>
      </>
   )
}
```

**app/docs/linux/page.tsx**:

```
export const Linux = () => {
   const PAGE_TITLE = "Linux";

   return (
      <div>Linux content</div>
   )
}
```

**app/docs/macos/page.tsx**:

```
export const MacOs = () => {
   const PAGE_TITLE = "MacOS";

   return (
      <div>MacOS content</div>
   )
}
```

I have no idea how to pass the `PAGE_TITLE` from sub pages to the header in `layout.tsx` so I have ended up using the URL pathname to check each page and update the `h2` accordingly.

**app/docs/layout.tsx**:

```
export const DocsLayout = ({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}) => {
   const pathname = usePathname();
   const [platform, setPlatform] = useState("Linux");

   if (pathname === "/docs/linux") {
      setPlatform("Linux");
   }
   else if (pathname === "/docs/macos") {
      setPlatform("MacOS");
   }

   return (
      <>
         <header>
             <h2>Documentation - {platform}</h2>
         </header>

         <div>{children}</div>
      </>
   )
}
```

I know this is not the ideal approach. Can someone help me fix this using the "right" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React Context. This will give you more flexibility and avoid relying on URL pathname.

Define a new context that will hold the current page title. Modify `DocsLayout` component to provide the context value. Then update the subpages to consume and set the context value.

**Create the Page Title Context** :

```
// Create a new file, e.g., PageTitleContext.js
import React from 'react';

export const PageTitleContext = React.createContext({
  pageTitle: '', // Initial value
  setPageTitle: () => {} // Placeholder function
});
```

**Update DocsLayout to Provide Context** :

```
// app/docs/layout.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PageTitleContext } from './PageTitleContext'; // Import the context

export const DocsLayout = ({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}) => {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState('');

  return (
    <PageTitleContext.Provider value={{ pageTitle, setPageTitle }}>
      <header>
        <h2>Documentation - {pageTitle}</h2>
      </header>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </PageTitleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Consume Context in Subpages** :

```
// app/docs/linux/page.tsx
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { PageTitleContext } from '../PageTitleContext'; // Import the context

export const Linux = () => {
  const { setPageTitle } = useContext(PageTitleContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPageTitle("Linux");
  }, [setPageTitle]);

  return (
    <div>Linux content</div>
  );
};

// Similar changes will be made in app/docs/macos/page.tsx
```